# How to copy text from the active tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I  have created a tab menu with three buttons. I can copy individual tab content after passing the `<div>` id. How can I get the ID of the active `<div>` so that I can pass the ID via `range.selectNode(document.getElementById(*ID*))`to copy the content of the currently active tab?

```js
//  function to copy
function CopyToClipboard(){
   var range = document.createRange();

   range.selectNode(document.getElementById("Cricket"));

   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); /* clear current selection*/
   window.getSelection().addRange(range); /* to select text*/
   document.execCommand("copy");
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();/* to deselect*/
}

function openGame(evt, GameName){
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(GameName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard()" >Copy</button>
<p>Click to copy:</p>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openGame(event, 'Cricket')">Cricket</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openGame(event, 'Football')">Football</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openGame(event, 'Chess')">Chess</button>
</div>
  
<div class="container" id="frame">
  <div id="Cricket" class="tabcontent"> 
    <p>Cricket</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Football" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Football</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Chess" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Chess</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this example, all you have to do is to store the active tab ID in a variable outside of those functions scopes.

```js
//  function to copy
var activeTabId = 'Cricket'; // Or whatever your default tab is

function CopyToClipboard(){
   var range = document.createRange();

   //range.selectNode(document.getElementById("Cricket"));
   range.selectNode(document.getElementById(activeTabId)); // here you use the variable
   
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); /* clear current selection*/
   window.getSelection().addRange(range); /* to select text*/
   document.execCommand("copy");
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();/* to deselect*/
}

function openGame(evt, GameName){
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(GameName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    
    activeTabId = GameName; // here you assign the active tab value
}
```

Also.
You may want to get the references for your tabs in advance - so you don't search the DOM each time your both of your functions are executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply adjust your CopyToClipboard function to this:

I use querySelector to get the active tablink element, then get it's inner text which is one of the tabcontent ids.

```
//  function to copy
function CopyToClipboard(){
  var activeTabId = document.querySelector('.tablinks.active').innerText;

   var range = document.createRange();

   range.selectNode(document.getElementById(activeTabId));

   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); /* clear current selection*/
   window.getSelection().addRange(range); /* to select text*/
   document.execCommand("copy");
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();/* to deselect*/
}
```

Comment: `innerText` just happened to be the same as ID. You should avoid such things "in real life" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function CopyToClipboard() inside openGame() like `CopyToClipboard(GameName)` and make change range.select node to  `range.selectNode(document.getElementById(GameName));`

also pass an parameter while defining the copy to clipboard function.

Comment: The CopyToClipboard() function should be called only when the copy button is clicked. Otherwise, previous clipboard content would be updated in each tab switching operation.

Comment: The openGame() is triggered when clicking the button resulting in the copy function running after that. doing this you can remove the copy button.
Alternatively,
in the copy function you can get the inner html of the `class = 'tabcontent'` and remove the `<p>` from the code to make sure only the game name gets copied.

Comment: Yes, I get your point. One extra button would not be required. Actually my target is to make the copy operation optional. Here, by putting "copy function" inside openGame(), not only switch tab but also copy the content.  
Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: From UX perspective. Do not run the code which does things user might never intended. "Changing a tab" vs "copying its content" are two completely different tasks. Plus - be careful with clipboard actions. It's system-wide. You might not want to override some copied password, or a picture, or a bank account or whatever due to a tab change.

Answer (score 0):

Question: "How can I get the ID of the active `<div>`?"

To answer that specific question:

The active button has classes 'tablinks active', and it's innerHTML contains text identical to the ID of the active div.

This function will retrieve text matching the div's ID from the active button:

```js
  // return the active div's ID
  function activeDivId () {
    let activeButtons =
      document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks active');
    if (activeButtons.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    const activeButton = activeButtons[0];
    return activeButton.innerHTML;
  }
```

---

#### Making it Better

While this strictly answers the question, it is not the most efficient method, and there are several ways to make the code better.

The following principles may guide the improvements:

1. Always store an app's state outside of the DOM.
2. For speed, minimize query and manipulation of the DOM.
3. To avoid naming conflicts, enclose variable and function names in an object.
4. Avoid using indexed for loops when `for...of` or `for...in` will suffice.

Here's a modified version of this game that follows these principles:

```js
  // put game inside an object to avoid global name conflicts
  const myGame = {

    // static parts of the DOM
    tabcontent: document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent'),
    tablinks: document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks'),

    // name of currently active game
    activeGame: null,

    // div of active game content
    activeTabContent: null,

    // button of active game
    activeTabLink: null,

    // open the game
    openGame: function (button, gameName) {

      const { tablinks, tabcontent } = myGame;

      // clear former active game
      if (myGame.activeGame) {
        myGame.activeTabLink.classList.remove('active');
        myGame.activeTabContent.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        // clear all games
        for (const tl of tablinks) {
          tl.classList.remove('active');
        }
        for (const tc of tabcontent) {
          tc.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      // activate new game
      myGame.activeTabLink = button;
      myGame.activeGame = gameName;
      myGame.activeTabContent = document.getElementById(gameName);
      myGame.activeTabContent.style.display = 'block';
      myGame.activeTabLink.classList.add('active');
    },

    // copy contents of active game
    copyActiveToClipboard: function () {
      const range = document.createRange();

      range.selectNode(myGame.activeTabContent);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); /* clear current selection*/
      window.getSelection().addRange(range); /* to select text*/
      document.execCommand("copy");
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();/* to deselect*/
    }
  };
```

```css
/* highlight active button */
.tablinks.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Copy contents of active game to clipboard:</p>
<button onclick="myGame.copyActiveToClipboard()">Copy</button>
<p>Click to select game:</p>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="myGame.openGame(this, 'Cricket')">Cricket
  </button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="myGame.openGame(this, 'Football')">Football
  </button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="myGame.openGame(this, 'Chess')">Chess
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="frame">
  <div id="Cricket" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Cricket</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Football" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Football</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Chess" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Chess</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The function doesn't return the ID, but `innerHTML`. Please do not suggest semantically incorrect solutions :). Also - this will search the DOM each time this function is run - it introduces a 3rd function that searches the DOM for the same thing. Further stacking might cause noticeable performance issues.

Comment: The specific question was answered correctly. There are better patterns, of course. But that was not the question.

Comment: All the respect sir, but when answering the question you are also teaching that person. You should feel responsible to suggest the best solution you can come up with. Otherwise you could say that setting up back-end with database and REST API also answers the question. Regards.

Comment: Alrighty then, I added a revised version that demonstrates improvements.